# XSLT - place existing nodes in different position

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have xml like follows,

```
<doc>
  <section>
    <p note="edit"></p>
    <p note="foot"></p>
    <p note="front"></p>
    <c>content</c>
  </section>
  <section>
  .......
  </section>
</doc>
```

what I need is get rid of `<p>` nodes which has attribute edit or foot and add them in to end of `<section>` node.

so the output should be

```
  <doc>
      <section>
        <p note="front"></p>
        <c>content</c>
      </section>   
      <p note="edit"></p>
      <p note="foot"></p>          

      <section>
      .......
      </section>
   </doc>
```

I can remove that nodes by simply using empty templates like follows,

```
<xsl:template match="p[@note='edit']"/>
<xsl:template match="p[@note='foot']"/>
```

but I cannot this about any method how can I placed those removed nodes at the end of the `<section>` node.

Any suggestions how can I do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="p[@note='edit' or @note='foot']"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p[@note='edit' or @note='foot']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**brief explanation :**

- `<xsl:template match="node()|@*">...` : Identity template. I'll just assume you're familiar with it.
- `<xsl:template match="section">...` : This is where the logic of, copying *'`<p>` nodes which has attribute edit or foot'* to the place after current `<section>`, resides.
- `<xsl:template match="p[@note='edit' or @note='foot']"/>` : Empty template to remove *'`<p>` nodes which has attribute edit or foot'* from the original location.

Comment: This slightly simpler expression may also work in XSLT 2.0 : `p[@note=('edit','foot')]` instead of `p[@note='edit' or @note='foot']` (I don't have the tool to test)

Comment: `p[@note=('edit','foot')] ` expression works in XSLT 2.0 . Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

For this case, I propose to use a xsl:choose inside a template matched the section.
This template creates the section element and reorders the nodes.

```
   <xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="p[@note= 'front']">
            <section>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@note= 'front'] | c"/>
            </section>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@note != 'front']"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <section>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </section>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rNa/3

Answer (score 1):

Or simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:variable name="footnotes" select="p[@note='edit' or @note='foot']" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except $footnotes"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$footnotes"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your XSLT there is the output of the <section> element, inside you use the <xsl:template match="p[@note='edit']"/> (and foot) as empty templates to avoid inserting these (I guess).
Just after the <section> element you can use the element

```
<xsl:template match="/doc/section/p[@note='edit']|/doc/section/p[@note='foot']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/> 
</xsl:template>
```

for inserting these here.